# ASP.NET MVC Razor set style attribute in foreach

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to set the width of a div via the style `Attribute` (to use the div as a bootstrap progress bar. I want to do this in a `foreach` loop

```
 @foreach (var item in Items)
      {
        <tr>
          <td>@item.Name</td>
          <td>
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@item.PercentageCompleted" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: @item.PercentageCompleted;">

              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      }  `
```

What happens is that the style `attribute` is empty. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What are the values of `PercentageCompleted`? Are they just a number or are they `##px`, `##%` etc?

Comment: they are just a number, but different for every entry in the items list.

Comment: Just tested and it does generate the `style` attribute but it would not be valid - you would need something like `style="@string.format("width: {0}%;", item.PercentageCompleted)"` to make it valid

Comment: the result is '<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="91,093700" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style=""></div>' Interestingly html in visual studio looks good and contains a 'style' attribute value, but in the browser it does not.

Comment: Not for me - it results in `style="width: 1"`  :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what value your `PercentageCompleted` property gives.

If it is just a `double` number representing % (e.g. `50.1`), you will need to append the `%` symbol to the end of your `@item.PercentageCompleted` like this:

```
... style="width: @(item.PercentageCompleted)%;">
```

wrapping the Razor content in parentheses to avoid errors. This would give you `style="width: 50.1%"`

If you are wanting to set the value in pixels, you will need to do the same, but add `px` to the end of your Razor code:

```
... style="width: @(item.PercentageCompleted)px;">
```

Most CSS attributes do not accept vanilla numbers (with the exception of `0`); it needs to have a type defined to quantify what measurements to use the value for e.g. `px`, `%`, `em`, `vh` etc.

View [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) to see more information on CSS units. Very useful.

Comment: I have tired the code above and it still produces a empty style attribute. I have tried both ways, none worked

Comment: @crauscher That's rather unusual. Next steps I would take would be:
    1: Grab a coffee;
    2: Stick a breakpoint in your debugger where it uses the item.PercentageCompleted property, and see what value it is (to check what should be coming out the other end). Small chance, but it might be empty/invalid;
    3: If your item.PercentageCompleted property looks OK, in your browser use the "Inspector" to view the element's inline style attribute. The browser's inspector is usually pretty good at showing you errors with CSS syntax.

Let me know how you get on and I'll try and advise further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a culture problem. Using a ',' as decimal seperator in the with does not work, using a '.' works.