# Style attribute rendered empty in .NET Core Razor view

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, attributes, styles

I have a similar issue to this one, however, can't figure out what's wrong and cannot find any documentation saying that it is a security feature or whatever:

[ASP.NET MVC Razor set style attribute in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001838/asp-net-mvc-razor-set-style-attribute-in-foreach)

I'm trying to render an element with the style attribute and it always comes out empty (the attribute).
Here is the code:

```
<div style="background-color: @Model.Theme;">@Html.Raw(Model.Theme)</div>
```

The output is `<div style="">#0000FF</div>`

What am I missing? It seems to be stripping the style value even if I hard-code it as a string.

(This was a testing code, I don't really need to use it, just curious what's happening.)

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, if pass a null value to the background-color, the 'background-color' should also be rendered. I suggest you to provide all the views , because the problem may lies there.

Comment: I was using this IdentityServer template https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/4_JavaScriptClient. I was trying to customize the login screen based on the parameter passed from the app and just accidentally found this problem, might be related to something internal, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code snippet and it works fine.

In the model class "Theme" prop provided as follows:

```
public string Theme {get;set;} = "#0000FF";
```

Razor view looks like

```
 <div style="background-color: @Model.Theme;">@Html.Raw(@Model.Theme)</div>
```

Got the result as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ScareCrow, I was using this sample app https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts/4_JavaScriptClient, it must be something internal what is stripping the style value.